# My code shows JSON decoder error for this url but it works for other urls. Is it a problem with the url

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import json
import requests

def get_quote():
    response = requests.get(
        "http://kitkabackend.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:5010/highscore/crowns/list?Country=GB&start=0&count=1")
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    quote = str(json_data["scores"][0]["User"]["Crowns"])
    return (quote) 


quote = get_quote()  
print(quote)
```

Why is this giving me JSON decoder error and how do i fix this?

Comment: You only need `response.json()`, by the way

Comment: In any case, the URL isn't the issue, it's the server response. If it fails to parse, it's not proper JSON, and there's nothing you can do to fix it if you don't control the server

Comment: Your code works fine, it prints `1046` when I run it

Comment: Check if you get `response.ok` before calling `json.loads(response.text)` or `response.json()`